# problem update svn. UTF-8

Tags: svn

подскажите пожалуйста что означает следующая ошибка и как ее исправить?

```
igor52@ws2 /web $ svn up
Updating '.':
svn: E000022: Error converting entry in directory '/web/media/sync-products' to UTF-8
svn: E000022: Valid UTF-8 data
(hex: 31 33 33 33 34 20)
followed by invalid UTF-8 sequence
(hex: c4 e8 f1 ef)
```

я так понимаю что кодировка не задалась svn'ну
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если читаешь по-английски, посмотри вот этот пост на SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116718/svn-error-cant-convert-string-from-native-encoding-to-utf-8

Там детально описано как это лечится.